# Python, match by index some lists into a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

So I have something like :

```
l1=[1,2,3]
l2=[4,5,6]
l3=[7,8,9]
```

Expected output is : `ls=[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]`

What it will be the most corect way to do that?

Comment: Writing code is probably the most correct way.

Answer (score 7):

Use `zip` and then list comprehension to turn the `tuple`s into `list`s

```
[list(x) for x in zip(l1, l2, l3)]
```

Result:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> l1=[1,2,3]
>>> l2=[4,5,6]
>>> l3=[7,8,9]
>>> zip(l1, l2, l3)
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

The built-in function zip will help you with what you want.

Comment: You and Moses Koledoye answered at the same time, **exactly** (in seconds). That's the most satisfying thing that happened to me today.

Comment: Moses Koledoye answered 6s before *

Comment: @Stages Nope http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38483818/timeline

Comment: If you get the same amount of votes, I'll celebrate for the whole night.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun how did you get the timeline pls?

Answer (score 5):

`zip` the three lists:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = [4,5,6]
>>> l3 = [7,8,9]
>>> zip(l1,l2,l3)
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Use a *list comprehension* to *cast* the tuples into lists to have a list of lists:

```
>>> [list(i) for i in zip(l1,l2,l3)]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: The mention of the list comprehension and casting makes this the more valid answer

Comment: Which I mentioned first, but oh well. :D

Comment: Looked like he posted first, but the timeline shows otherwise, either way the list comprehension is what OP is looking for